# Printing in Silverlight cuts off some portion

Tags: silverlight, printing

How do I provide a print option on my silverlight application. I am able to print using the PrintDocument class but it cuts of the edges. 
Is there a way to shrink the view to fit in a print paper. Thanks for any help.
I am using the below code:

```
PrintDocument document = new PrintDocument();
document.PrintPage += (s, args) =>
{
args.PageVisual = this.LayoutRoot;
};
document.Print("Silverlight Print Application Demo");
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two conceptually different tasks here:

1. Printing an element *as rendered in the ui at some point* and
2. Render an element exclusively for printing.

Since you're complaining about the cutting off of edges, I assume you want to do the latter. For that, I wouldn't add the current control's layout root, which I suspect you're doing. Add something that is not yet added to the visual tree, or remove it from its parent before printing.

If you have to remove it first for some reason (perhaps because the user needs to interact with it first), then store the element in a variable `printedPage` that you can re-add to the visual tree on the `PrintDocument.EndPrint` event.

For the main event handler use something like this:

```
    void HandlePrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        var panel = new Grid();

        // get an element to print that is not attached to the visual tree
        printedPage = GetDetachedPageToPrint();

        panel.Children.Add(printedPage.ReportPage);

        // we wrap it in a Viewbox to make it full-page
        var viewbox = new Viewbox() { Child = panel };

        // we need to have a measure pass
        viewbox.Measure(e.PrintableArea);

        e.PageVisual = viewbox;

        // for more pages, we would need to be more careful
        //with parent detachments
        e.HasMorePages = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem a couple of months ago and tried several solutions.

I`ve already answered this question in another post. Please check out this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20896774/1141477

It converts the framework element into images and fit it inside a rectangle, which is from the same size as the printableArea. It worked well to me.

Hope it helps!